# Replace White Spaces with sed

Tags: replace, sed

I have a large file (100M rows) in the following format:

```
Week      |ID           |Product |Count     |Price
---------- ------------- -------- ---------- -----   
2016-01-01|00056001     |172     |23        |3.50
2016-01-01|1            |125     |15        |2.75
```

I am trying to use sed to add Xs to the missing digits on the second customer ID, but maintain the number of spaces after the full ID.  So, the table would look like:

```
Week      |ID           |Product |Count     |Price
---------- ------------- -------- ---------- -----   
2016-01-01|00056001     |172     |23        |3.50
2016-01-01|1XXXXXXX     |125     |15        |2.75
```

I have tried

```
 sed -i "s/\s\{29,\}/XXXXXXX                      /g" *.csv
```

and

```
sed -i -- "s/1                              /1XXXXXXX                       /g" *.csv
```

Neither with any change to the file.  What am I missing?

Thanks.

EDIT for clarification:  There are 29 spaces after the 1 in the actual data.  I used less on the example table for readability sake.  I assume whatever solution works will apply no matter the number of spaces.

Comment: are you sure the `-i` option of sed means "in-place"? On some systems it means something else, which is confusing.

Comment: It means in-place when I use it for my typical replace procedures (I have to run a specific command line once a month on some data we get)... -i always replaces inline for me

Comment: Also, I tried -e just because I saw it sround for this type of thing.  I ended up with 100M lines scrolling through my command window :)

Comment: okay so why the 29 spaces whereas your input samples seem to only have a few ones like 15.

Comment: Apologies- there are 29 in the real data.  I thought I'd make the table on here a little easier to look at.  I'll edit for clarification

Comment: Can you check with a hexdump (`xxd`?) that there are really spaces, no tabs or other invisible characters?

Comment: Can I use xxd to check a specific line?

Comment: We have a winner, @choroba ...Every other space is actually a null character, not a space, I guess.  The lines alternate between HEX 00 and Hex 20...I assume that's what that means?

Comment: @datahappy: Maybe UTF-16? Can you add the dump to the question?

Answer (score 2):

That works for me (not using `\s` but merely space, and dropped the useless `g` option because needed once per line only):

```
sed -i "s/[ ]\{29,\}/XXXXXXX                      /" *.csv
```

Although for safety reasons I would rather use a more restrictive script which would perform the substitution only if `|1` is encountered:

```
sed -i "s/\(\|1\)[ ]\{29,\}/\1XXXXXXX                      /" *.csv
```